# How to get the hidden states of a fine-tuned TFBertModel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I first fine-tune the Bert model on a text classification task and but then I want to get the embeddings of the fine-tuned model in TensorFlow. Unfortunately, I can only say `output_hidden_states=True`, in the first line where I download the pre-trained Bert model but not in the second stage where I create a `tf.Keras.Model`. Here is the code for how I make and train the model:

```
max_len = 55

from transformers import BertConfig, BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

def build_custome_model():
    bert_encoder = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(Base_BERT_Path)

    input_word_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    input_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
    input_type_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_type_ids")
    
    embedding = bert_encoder([input_word_ids, input_mask, input_type_ids])[0]
    clf_output = embedding[:,0,:]

    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(clf_output)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(net)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask, input_type_ids], outputs=output)

    model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

Then I train the model on a dataset with 2 sentences and as score for their similarity

```
#------Training with stratifiedkfold-------


k = 5
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = k, shuffle = True)

for i, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(kfold.split(first_sentences, labels.score), 1):

    epoch_evaluation = {}

    train_input = create_input(np.array(first_sentences)[train_idx], np.array(second_sentences)[train_idx], tokenizer, max_len=max_seq_length)
    validation_input = create_input(np.array(first_sentences)[val_idx], np.array(second_sentences)[val_idx], tokenizer, max_len=max_seq_length)

    history = model.fit(x = train_input, y = labels.loc[train_idx, 'score'],
                        validation_data= (validation_input, labels.loc[val_idx, 'score']),
                        epochs = 5,
                        verbose = 1,
                        batch_size = 8)
```

My goal is to have a model at the end that is trained on this dataset and can output the embeddings (first layer of the hidden states (output[2][0])) whenever I give it a sentence so that I can get the mean of all the fine-tuned token embeddings of a sentence.

Comment: are you using hugging-face library ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question and added how I import the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the embeddings with the [get_input_embeddings](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.TFPreTrainedModel.get_input_embeddings) function:

```py
model = build_custome_model():

model.layers[3].get_input_embeddings()(input_ids)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem is that this model only outputs 5 labels after fine-tuning. What I want is to also be able to get the encoding(embedding) of a sentence that I give it after training it on a dataset and get the mean embeddings for each sentence. I tried adding the hidden states to the outputs of the tf.Keras.Model, but the process of training got very slow.

Comment: Do you want all hidden states (i.e. output from each BertEncoder layer) or only the output of the last hidden state? @mitramirshafiee

Comment: I only want the embeddings (the first layer of the last output of the model which is modelOutput [2][0] or modelOutput[''hidden_states''][0]) to get the mean of all token embeddings after training the model on a dataset with 5 labels.

Comment: @mitramirshafiee Sorry I misunderstood you in the first place. I think the training is slowing down because you are filling up your RAM. You are probably looking for `model.layers[3].get_input_embeddings()(input_ids)`. I will edit my question in case this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm still not quite sure though, does this function(get_input_embeddings() ) give me the embeddings of the model that has been fine tuned because the results don't seem that much different from BERT now and I'm a bit worried it is actually outputting the main BERT embeddings before training.

Comment: No, it returns the actual embedding layer (i.e. after the training). That it looks similar just shows that your data is not that much different from the data used for the pretraining of BERT. @mitramirshafiee